# What part of this HTACCESS file is causing the infinite loop?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to shorten the string for user profile pages, but I'm a little new to .htaccess files. I have been trying to find out why this keeps looping, but I'm having a hard time finding it. If anyone could please either show me how to fix it or at least point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /register_demo/profile.php?username=$1
```

The error I'm getting is '500 Internal Server' on my browser, and when I look in my error log, I am seeing I am exceeding the internal recursion limit.

I also noticed the url changes from:

```
localhost/register_demo/profile.php?username=username
```

to
    localhost/register_demo/profile.php?username=profile.php

Comment: Hard to say without a sample of the entered URL and the description of the error.

Comment: Does `/register_demo/profile.php` exist?

Comment: Yes, `/register_demo/profile.php` does exist. And it's a 500 Internal Server Error. I looked in my error log and it seems like I've exceeded the internal recursion limit. I was reading that 10 is a lot to begin with, so I was looking to fix my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using round brackets around `REQUEST_FILENAME`! Change them to curly brackets.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /register_demo/profile.php?username=$1
```